# Why ansible ping module task is remote execution type?

Tags: ansible, ping

Ansible has two execution types: remote, local

Local execution type is like invoking REST api call  from ansible server and receiving http response

---

After running below command from ansible server:

`ansible 192.168.33.20 -i inventory -u vagrant -m ping -k -vvv`

`-vvv` option shows that:

`ping` package is transferred to target server(`192.168.33.20`) and compiled into binary.

`ping` is then **executed on remote** machine(`192.168.33.20`) as

`/usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-111111.44.555555/ping`

and then runs

`rm -rf /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-111111.44.555555/ >/dev/null 2>&1`

on `192.168.33.20`

---

But, `ping` command is supposed to run from machine other than `192.168.33.20` to test the response from `192.168.33.20`.

Why ansible `ping` module task is remote execution type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ping package is transferred to target server(192.168.33.20) and compiled into binary.

Ansible doesn't compile anything to a binary. It transfers the module over and runs it, with no transformation taking place.

> But, ping command is supposed to run from machine other than 192.168.33.20 to test the response from 192.168.33.20.

You are confusing Ansible's `ping` module with the `ping` command.  The `ping` module is basically a do-nothing module that confirms Ansible is able to communicate with the remote host.  It's sort of the equivalent of running:

```
ssh remotehost true
```

It doesn't *do* anything, it just returns successfully.

Comment: To confirm ansible server is able to communicate with reomte host, `ping` module should be run in ansible server(where ansible is installed) that talks to remote host. Isn't it? Running `ping` module local to remote host doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: The `ping` module is used to verify that Ansible can successfully communicate with the remote host. That means (a) connect to the remote host, (b) copy over a module, (c) run it, (d) read a response.